# Preprocessor Definition in VS2010 for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to understand the need and usage of pre processor definitions in C++. I understand the use of include guards #ifndef #define and #endif. But I don't exactly understand the usage of the need of:

```
Open the project's Property Pages dialog box.
Click the C/C++ folder.
Click the Preprocessor property page.
Modify the Preprocessor Definitions property.
```

Comment: That's just a method of doing `#define` without changing your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `#ifdef` or `#ifndef` in your source files, this is *one* of the places where you can influence the results of those tests.

Comment: OK so does that mean if I have some code #ifndef TEST32 code; code; code #endif and I put TEST32 in the "Preprocessor Definition" as I have mentioned above and I need not include #define TEST32 in my code. I I don't add TEST32 to Preprocessor Definitions then I need to include #define TEST32 in my code. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Right, that's a place to add defines without editing the source code.

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor definitions are use for global pre-processor definitions for the current project; usually system or compiler pre-processor defintion.

for example, when in debug mode, one of the definition will _DEBUG this will be used when compiling the code if the user (programmer) wants to do something different when building in debug mode :

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
/// do something ONLY in debug mode
#endif
```